# Moment of Inertia of a Solid Sphere - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: classical-mechanics, moment-of-inertia

I am trying to calculate the moment of inertia of a solid sphere about an axis through its center, however I am getting a wrong answer, when it's supposed to be 2MR^2/5. What am I doing wrong?

[image: han]

I integrated over hollow spheres was radii from 0 to R and found that their masses were their surface area multiplied by dr. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the density. For a homogeneous mass distribution the $r$ you should be writing in the density is the radius of the ball, as opposed to the integration variable. Therefore you should be integrating an $r^{4}dr/R^{3}$, where $R$ is the radius of the ball, not an $rdr$:

$$
I=\frac{3M}{R^{3}}\int_{0}^{R}r^{4}dr=\frac{3MR^{2}}{5}
$$

Where does the "incorrect" factor of $3/2$ come from? It comes from the actual definition of the inertia **tensor** (which is the one that gives $2/5$ as the correct prefactor),

$$
I_{ij}=\int\ (r^{2}\delta_{ij}-r_{i}r_{j})\ dm
$$

For spherically symmetric bodies (both in shape and density) you can show that $I_{xx}=I_{yy}=I_{zz}$, $I_{ij}=0$ for $i\neq j$, provided that the axes pass through the center of the sphere. Therefore

$$
I_{xx}=I_{yy}=I_{zz}=\frac{1}{3}(I_{xx}+I_{yy}+I_{zz})=\frac{1}{3}\ \delta^{ij}I_{ij}=\frac{1}{3}\int\ (r^{2}\delta^{ij}\delta_{ij}-\delta^{ij}r_{i}r_{j})\ dm=\\ =\frac{1}{3}\int\ (3r^{2}-r^{2})\ dm=\frac{2}{3}\ I=\frac{2MR^{2}}{5}
$$

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot.